# Android: Bitmovin I cant find the encoded video in the bitmovin console?

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash, bitmovin-player

I have been searching all around the web to try to understand how to stream videos to my android app.

**I learned:**

That the videos must be in the `HLS` or `MPEG-DASH` format to be adaptive for streaming .

**What I mean by adaptive streaming:**

The kind of streaming that allows the user to change the quality while video is streaming.

**What could help me do this:**

The first thing should be to encode my videos into an `HLS` or `MPEG-DASH`, for that I found a service that could do this which is [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/).

The second thing is to play the adaptive video, I found two ways [exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and [Bitmovin-player](https://bitmovin.com/video-player/).

**The problem:**

I made an account on bitmovin and tried to test an mp4 video to encode, but there are too many stuff there like input, output and manifest and I don't know what URL I should use to pass to the bitmovin player to play. I encoded the video but I don't know where the reference to the enocoded video is.

**My question:**

1) Is my approach of streaming videos correct?

2) Can someone explain which url I must pass to the player or where I can find the video that was encoded in Bitmovin cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Is my approach of streaming videos correct?**
Short answer: Yes :) Adaptive streaming is used by almost every major VoD platform out there, and a proper way to do that. Further it allows you and your viewers to either

- let the player decide on its own to select the optimal quality for the given connection and device of the viewer to provide continuous playback
- and the viewer can select a specific quality on their own as well, if they want to.

When creating adaptive streaming content using MPEG-DASH and/or HLS as streaming format, your output would typically consist of the following:

- Video/Audio Segments
- MPD Manifest, and/or HLS playlists

1) Your input file (e.g. an mp4 file) will be downloaded and splitted into segments, which are being processed by the Bitmovin encoding. Out of these, it creates the different qualities the player or your viewer can choose from later.

2) This segmented output is then transferred back to your own storage, e.g. a cloud storage like AWS Simple Storage, or Google Cloud Storage. Other output types like (S)FTP and [many others](https://bitmovin.com/docs/encoding/articles/supported-input-output-storages) can be used as well.

3) In order to play your created MPEG-DASH or HLS content, a MPD manifest and/or HLS playlist needs to be created. Those are basically an index for the player, which tells it which qualities are available and where to find them to start the playback.

---

**2) Can someone explain which url I must pass to the player or where I can find the video that was encoded in Bitmovin cloud?**
The URL you would have to provide to the player, has to point the MPD and/or HLS master playlist, that gets transferred to your storage. Bitmovin doesn't offer a hosting service for your encoded content, which is why you didn't find an URL to the manifest that is used. So you would need a storage first, where the encoding could be transferred to.

Give the [getting started guide](https://bitmovin.com/dashboard/getting-started/encoding) a try. Select your preferred API client. Then you will be guided step by step on how to integrate this encoding service. I hope this helps :)

To test the playback of the player you can also have a look at https://bitmovin.com/demos/stream-test and select "Use our defaults" which provide URL's to sample content for testing the player and playback.

Comment: Thank you, just have few more questions, 1) for each mp4 video file I will get a master playlist url in the output storage? Can I use firebase storage to save these master playlists? Users must pay to watch my videos, I dont think it is a good idea to pass the master playlist url to the player through code (I cant hardcode the url through code in android) what should I do to secure the videos?

Comment: Hi again,

**Can I use firebase storage to save these master playlists?** Yes, that should work fine as well. Simply create a Google Storage and use your Firebase Storage bucketname accordingly. This [article](https://bitmovin.com/docs/encoding/faqs/how-can-i-create-access-secret-keys-for-google-cloud-storage) explains how to obtain an Access/Secret key pair for it.

Comment: **What should I do to secure the videos?** It depends on the grade of security you want to have. A [DRM solution](https://bitmovin.com/what-is-drm/) is a very common way to secure your content and its playback. Your content gets encrypted during the encoding process. In order to play it, you provide the URL to the Master playlist and a License Acquisition URL to the player. The latter is can be obtained from your DRM solution provider, and enables you to control who can play your content accordingly.